# Use trained model sentiment on the dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I have a dataframe

```
0         i only need uxy to hit 20 eod to make up for a...
1                                        oh this isn’t good
2         lads why is my account covered in more red ink...
3         i'm tempted to drop my last 800 into some stup...
4         the sell offs will continue until moral improves.
```

I want to apply NLP for each comment to identify which one is positive and which one is negative.

Here is what I have

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews
from random import shuffle
from nltk import FreqDist
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import string
from nltk import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk import classify
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
df = pd.read_csv("/home/yan/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/comments_binary.csv")

pos_reviews = []
for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids('pos'):
    words = movie_reviews.words(fileid)
    pos_reviews.append(words)

neg_reviews = []
for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids('neg'):
    words = movie_reviews.words(fileid)
    neg_reviews.append(words)

stopwords_english = stopwords.words('english')


def bag_of_words(words):
    words_clean = []

    for word in words:
        word = word.lower()
        if word not in stopwords_english and word not in string.punctuation:
            words_clean.append(word)

    words_dictionary = dict([word, True] for word in words_clean)

    return words_dictionary

# positive reviews feature set
pos_reviews_set = []
for words in pos_reviews:
    pos_reviews_set.append((bag_of_words(words), 'pos'))

# negative reviews feature set
neg_reviews_set = []
for words in neg_reviews:
    neg_reviews_set.append((bag_of_words(words), 'neg'))

shuffle(pos_reviews_set)
shuffle(neg_reviews_set)

test_set = pos_reviews_set[:200] + neg_reviews_set[:200]
train_set = pos_reviews_set[200:] + neg_reviews_set[200:]

classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)
accuracy = classify.accuracy(classifier, test_set)

custom_review = "I am pretty sure that TSLA will hit 500 today after open"
custom_review_tokens = word_tokenize(custom_review)
custom_review_set = bag_of_words(custom_review_tokens)
print (classifier.classify(custom_review_set)) # Output: pos
```

I am confused how would I apply the whole function for each row with text and create a separate column with pos and neg text that would describe a certain comment.
I tried to create a function

```
def my_classification(x):
    return classifier.classify(x)
df["new_column"] = df["text"].apply(my_classification)
```

But it says AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'copy'

I would highly appreciate your help